# JSON encoding array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jQuery graph which builds the x-axis like so:

```
xaxis: {
  tickColor: 'transparent',
  tickDecimals: 0,
  ticks: [[1,'27/07'],[2,'28/07'],[3,'29/07'],[4,'30/07'],[5,'31/07'],[6,'01/08'],[7,'02/08']]
},
```

I want the 'ticks' to be generated by a piece of javascipt that loops between 2 variable dates like so:

```
var i = 1;
var superArray = [];
var subArray = []; 

for (var d = d1; d <= d2; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {

  var m0 = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var d0 = d.getDate();

  m0 = m0 > 9 ? m0 : "0"+m0;
  d0 = d0 > 9 ? d0 : "0"+d0;

  var x = d0 + '/' + m0;

  subArray.push(i, x);
  superArray.push(subArray.slice(0));

  i++;

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(superArray));
```

The console.log looks like so:

```
[[1,"27/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07",5,"31/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07",5,"31/07",6,"01/08"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07",5,"31/07",6,"01/08",7,"02/08"]]
```

Which is kinda close to what I want but not quite!

How can I make this:

```
[[1,"27/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07",5,"31/07"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07",5,"31/07",6,"01/08"],[1,"27/07",2,"28/07",3,"29/07",4,"30/07",5,"31/07",6,"01/08",7,"02/08"]]
```

Look like this:

```
[[1,'27/07'],[2,'28/07'],[3,'29/07'],[4,'30/07'],[5,'31/07'],[6,'01/08'],[7,'02/08']]
```

Comment: Well, you're constantly adding items to `subArray` through `push` so yeah, that item will keep growing for every push to `superArray`. What you're trying to do is `var subArray = [i, x]; superArray.push(subArray);` Basically what @ItsJohnB said.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `subArray`.

Just use this one `superArray.push([i, x]);`

Comment: You might want to add an explanation of why OP doesn't need subArray and how it's messing up their code. Your answer as is ended you up in the "review for deletion" queue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by adding:

```
subArray.length = 0;
```

After

```
superArray.push(subArray.slice(0));
```

Comment: While this may work, it's not the solution you're looking for